# Shell/Python program: How to convert my log file into an vim quick fix format?

Tags: python, shell, gcc, vim, format

For example, I've got a big log file like this:

```
[2016-02-10 13:17:56.885597]    [WARNING]   [53171] [src/root/mylinux/test01.cpp:300]
```

As you could see, this format contain several parts:

```
1. The time stamp, day+hour+minute+second+microsecond
2. Some spaces and the [WARNING] or [ERROR] or [INFO] or [DEBUG], etc.
3. A process ID number like [53171]
4. The source file name + line number
```

I wish to change its format into something like gcc error information, like:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:5: error: ‘pp’ was not declared in this scope
```

I wish to use VIM+quick fix to navigate my log file and jump to source files, and see how the program executes.

So my requirement is: how to use shell programming or python programming to change my log file format into gcc error format like above?

Thanks.

Comment: Vim's `quickfix` is a data structure, not a file format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set Vim's `errorformat` option like this:

```
set errorformat+=\[%.%#\]\ \ \ \ \[%m\]\ \ \ \[%.%#\]\ \[%f:%l\]
```

which should give you the result below with the sample you gave:

[image: quickfix]

Hint: you can do `$ vim -q mylog` to open your log directly in the quickfix.